# Real world Opensource c# applications showing good code

Tags: c#, open-source, solid-principles

I have been reading up on SOLID principles and was wondering if there is a good large opensource application or project in DOTNET that shows SOLID principles in use in a real world product.

If there are any other opensource projects that are considered to be good coding samples I would be very intrested to see them these too.

Comment: Are you looking for web or windows applications?

Comment: For an example of ASP.NET MVC application you can use [Who can help me?](http://whocanhelpme.codeplex.com/)

Comment: It doesnt matter aslong as the good is good.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out:

- [ASP.NET MVC's source code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)
- The [Castle Project](http://www.castleproject.org/subversion.html) projects
- Ayende's [Rhino family](https://rhino-tools.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/rhino-tools/trunk/) of tools

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally up to date in .NET, but as far as I know .NET doesn't implement return type covariance, which goes against the L principle in "SOLID" (Liskov substitution principle).

Comment: so.... you can still write good and bad code in any language no matter the functionality. Are you seriously saying that all c# code is bad because of this?

Comment: Never said that, just that one of the SOLID principles cannot be implemented in C#. It's not a matter of code quality, it's a matter of discovering the SOLID principles in their entirety.

Comment: I can't see why this answer gets a -1. Sylvestre is correct, .NET does not implement return type covariance and so does not fully adhere to SOLID principles. IME this is not problem when working with .NET, but since the q. refers to SOLID it is worth pointing out I think!

Comment: I dare to disagree. This answer has no direct relation to the question.

Comment: @Kryzsztof - it speaks directly to the question, the questioner is looking for examples of SOLID, and technicaly speaking, .NET does not support the "L" in SOLID. It may be a pedantic point, but the question explicitly refered to SOLID so it is worth pointing out.

Comment: Ok, remind me, what does return type covariance have to do with LSP?

Comment: From wikipedia article on LSP : "Liskov's principle imposes some standard requirements on signatures that have been adopted in newer object-oriented programming languages (usually at the level of classes rather than types - see nominal vs. structural subtyping for the distinction):

Contravariance/covariance of method argument/return types in the subtype [...]"

Answer (score 2):

Not really an application, but FubuMVC and OpenRASTA frameworks are both written very well.